# How do you access data in a text file in a specific line in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Some background - I am creating a bot for Discord. This command, *claim*, will be used to claim a "job", or essentially tie their discord username to the job. The command will use the line number as the identifier for the job.

The problem I am having is that I can only access the first line in the job.txt file using this 'for' function. When I try to access the other lines, I get the 'This job does not exist!' error.

```
@bot.command()
async def claim(ctx, *, message=None):

    with open('job.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if num == int(message):
                print(line)
                break
            else:
                print('This job does not exist!')
                break
```

When I run the code like this...

```
@bot.command()
async def claim(ctx, *, message=None):

    with open('job.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if num == int(message):
                print(line)
                break
```

I can access each line which doesn't really make sense to me. Unfortunately, I need to be able to prevent someone from claiming a job that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you have a `break` on the `if` and on the `else`.  As a result, the loop always terminates after reading the first line from the file.  I suspect you want to go through all lines to find the matching message.

I would suggest keeping track of whether you found the job and handling that after the loop:

```
@bot.command()
async def claim(ctx, *, message=None):

    found_job = False
    with open('job.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if num == int(message):
                print(line)
                found_job = True
                break

    if found_job:
       # do your work here
    else:
       print("Uh-oh...didn't find the job")
```

Comment: I have tried removing the ```break``` but when I do, not only does the ```print``` command run but the ```else```  part of the if function runs as well.

And to clarify, I am testing this function to find the issue. The end result would be that if the command find this job that it will attach the user's id to the job and thus claiming the job. I don't necessarily need it to output that it has found the job.

Comment: Disregard what I wrote before, I see what you are saying.